# Apply edit to strings

Tags: string

I have an practice that gives input and wants to get the `'hello'`by deleting letters and if it get print `'YES'` and if not print `'NO'`.python 3

i write this but i do not know why it is not work sometime

```
def edit(x):
    for h in x:
        if h in ('a','q','z','w','s','x','d','c','r','f','v','t','g','b','y','n','u','j','m','i','k','p'):
            y = x.replace(h,'')

    return y


x =input()
x1='a'.join(x)
y = edit(x1)

if y==('hello'):
    print('YES')
elif y.count('l')>=2 and y.count('h')>=1  and y.count('e')>=1 and y.count('o')>=1:
    
    if y.startswith('h') and y.endswith('o'):
        y1=y.replace('h','')

        if y1.startswith('e'):
            y2=y1.replace('e','')
            if y2.startswith('l') and y2.endswith('o'):
                print('YES')

else:
    print('NO')
```

for example

```
aahhelllo
YES
```

```
asdxhhhellooooo

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Ma be try printing the value of `y` before printing `YES` or `NO` – then you'll see what was wrong with your `edit`ing result.

Comment: i try it sometime edit work but sometime dont work

Comment: And...? What's the result of `edit()` invoked on `"asdxhhhellooooo"`...? I dare to suspect it's _NOT_ `"hhhellooooo"`, but rather `"asxhhhellooooo"`.

Comment: yes .exactly it is not  "hhhellooooo"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in your `edit(x)` function. It iterates through characters of the string in the `x` variable and checks if the character is in the list of 22; if so, it removes all instances of a chosen character from the string and stores a result in the `y` variable.

Note: on every iteration it takes the `x` variable; it does not take `y`, which is a result of the previous modification, but it takes an original input parameter again and again. Finaly, you get `y` from the last modification performed.

In `"aahhelllo"` there is only one character to remove: `'a'`, so only one substitution is done and its result is `"hhello"`, as expected.

OTOH, in `"aasdxhhhellooooo"` there are four characters to be removed, so:

- in the first iteration `y` is assigned a value of `"aasdxhhhellooooo".replace('a','')` which is `"sdxhhhellooooo"`;
- in the second iteration you remove `'a'` again (because it was not deleted from `x`);
- in the third you assign `y="aasdxhhhellooooo".replace('s','')` which is `"aadxhhhellooooo"`;
- and so on, until the last modification done for `h=='x'`, which makes `y="aasdxhhhellooooo".replace('x','')`, which is `"aasdhhhellooooo"`.

And that is the result returned from `edit(x)` in the second case.